# How to make code chunks depend on all previous chunks in knitr/rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr

## Goal

I want to create my data analysis reproducible by making chunks depend on all previous chunks. So, if there are 3 chunks and I change something in the 1st chunk the subsequent 2 chunks should re-run so that they reflect the change made in the outputs. I want to add this condition in the global chunk options at the top of the document so that I don't have to use `dependson` multiple times.

## Problems

The outputs of a chunk don't change if it is not modified and `cache=TRUE`. For the chunks containing the code, I can make them dependable on all previous ones using following at the top of the document:

````
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
# set global chunk options: 
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, autodep = TRUE)
dep_auto()
```
````

If any of the above chunks is changed, all subsequent chunks are re-run. But this does not work if I use `source()` in chunks to read R scripts. Following is an example document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
# set global chunk options: 
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, autodep = TRUE)
dep_auto()
```


# Create Data
```{r}
#source("data1.R")
x <- data.frame(col1 = 4:10, col2 = 6:12)
x
```

# Summaries
```{r}
#source("data2.R")

median1.of.x <- sapply(x, function(x) median(x)-1)

sd.of.x <- sapply(x, sd)

plus.of.x <- sapply(x, function(x) mean(x)+1)

jj <- rbind(plus.of.x, sd.of.x, median1.of.x)

```

```{r}
jj
```
````

Now, if I change any of the 1st 2 chunks the third chunk gives correct output after `knit`ting. But if instead I put the first chunk's code in a source file `data1.R` and second chunk's in file `data2.R`, keeping the global chunk options same as before, if I make any changes in source files they are not reflected in the output of third chunk correctly. For example, changing `x` to `x <- data.frame(col1 = 5:11, col2 = 6:12)` should yield:

```
 > jj
                 col1      col2
plus.of.x    9.000000 10.000000
sd.of.x      2.160247  2.160247
median1.of.x 8.000000  9.000000
```

But with use of `source()` as discussed above, the `knitr` document reports:

```
 jj
##                col1      col2
## mean.of.x  5.000000  9.000000
## sd.of.x    2.160247  2.160247
## minus.of.x 6.000000 10.000000
```

What settings do I need to change to use `source` in `knitr` docs correctly?

Comment: when you use the `source` method, you are commenting out the `x <- data.frame()` line, correct?

Comment: Knitr isn't very suitable for the kind of declarative workflow you need to make this happen. I'd recommend make & makefiles, or if your want to stay completely within R, the excellent [remake package](https://github.com/richfitz/remake)

Comment: @rawr Yes, I only keep the `source` command and comment out all others.

Comment: @Ben I'll look into `remake`. But is my goal here impossible in `knitr`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use `source()`, **knitr** is unable to analyze the possible objects to be created from it; **knitr** must be able to see the full source code to analyze the dependencies among code chunks. There are two approaches to solve your problem:

1. Tell the second chunk that it depends on the value of `x` by adding an arbitrary chunk option that uses the value of `x`, e.g. ```` ```{r cache.extra = x} ````; then whenever `x` changes, the cache of this code chunk will be automatically invalidated ([more info](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/));
2. Let **knitr** see the full source code; you can pass the source code to a code chunk via the chunk option `code`, e.g. ```` ```{r code = readLines('data1.R')} ```` (same for `data2.R`); then `dep_auto()` should be able to figure out `x` was created from the first chunk, and used in the second chunk, so the second chunk must depend on the first chunk.

Comment: Thank you very much, Yihui. Generally, what would be your advice to approach a data analysis project? Is using `source` recommended to gather/create data?

Comment: Could a third approach be using `read_chunk('data1.R')`, following [example 113](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/113-externalization.Rmd)?

Comment: @umairdurrani I don't have general advice here but if you want to put some R code in separate R scripts, you can either use the `code` option I mentioned, or `read_chunk()` as @Ben mentioned (you will have to label the code chunks). `source()` is fine in general, and I cannot think of other cases in which it can be problematic.

Comment: Building on Yihui's first suggestion, you could introduce `cache.extra = tools::md5sum("data1.R")`, which would check if anything in the file has changed (although the second suggestion seems better, if possible).

Answer (score 4):

I found that this works (knitr 1.17):

```
<<..., dependson=all_labels()>>=
...
@
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Using R Markdown, the exact syntax I had to use was `{r chunk-name, dependson=knitr::all_labels()}`

Answer (score 0):

I think, by default, chunks do depend on previous chunks, and the author went to great lengths to try to make each chunk start with the same environment that the last one ended (although there are numerous ways of screwing this up, like sourcing files with caching turned on...) I can't recall the syntax, but you can include knitr chunks in external documents. There is also a trick to reuse knitr chunks in the same doc in a function-like manner by reusing the label, and you may be able to build some non linear dependency from this. But why not set cache to FALSE when you don't want caching? Sourcing seems like a bad idea but I can't put my finger on why. I would make the knitr workflow linear and put logic in functions, and turn off caching if the same function call can return different things with the same input parameters.

Another trick that might be useful to you is the recently added ability to knit a document using input parameters. This could possibly extract some logic from your knitr doc, which I think is the avoidable root of your problems.

Comment: `cache=FALSE` is ok for this example but for computationally intensive chunks it is a really bad idea. Using `source` is useful if you want to use the same chunk in multiple docs. Code externalization in knitr is possible but it requires use of all the chunks which are interdependent. That's why `source` is a better choice. Perhaps data reading step should be explicitly defined in the first chunk.

Comment: I guess your other option is using a different caching mechanism. I like R.cache. I know it feels like knitr should be able to do what you want, but, having been through this myself, I found it better just to keep the knitr doc very simple and get the logic into an actual programming language, eg R!